# Difference between IOHandlers when there is no SSL

Tags: delphi, ssl, delphi-xe5, indy10

I am using Indy to get JSON from a url address. My code is using `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` as `IOHandler` for `TIdHTTP`.

```
var IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL; // IO handler #1
    IdnoSSL: TIdIOHandlerStack;          // IO handler #2
    JSON: String;
```

I'm curious, if there is some reason to use SSL as handler, when the url is simple `http://www.example.com`, not `https://www.example.com`?

```
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;

  try
    IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;

    // IdnoSSL:= TIdIOHandlerStack.Create(IdHTTP);
    // IdHTTP.IOHandler :=  IdnoSSL;

    JSON := IdHTTP.Get('http://www.example.com');
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or should I remove `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` and use noSSL with `TIdIOHandlerStack`?

Any help or advice is appriecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you assign `IdSSL`, `TIdHTTP` will automatically enable/disable it depending on whether an HTTP or HTTPS url is being requested.  So, you could just assign `IdSSL` always, and let `TIdHTTP` decide how to use it.

On the other hand, if you don't need HTTPS at all, you don't really need to assign any `IOHandler` at all (you almost never need `IdnoSSL`).  When connecting to a server, Indy will create a default `TIdIOHandlerStack` for you if an `IOHandler` has not been assigned yet.

If you are using an up-to-date version of Indy, and do no need to customize SSL/TLS settings, then [you don't need to manually assign an `IOHandler` for HTTPS](http://indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changelog/20141222.aspx).

However, if you attempt to request an HTTPS url without an SSL `IOHandler` assigned (manually or otherwise), you will get an `EIdIOHandlerPropInvalid` exception.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to assign no `IOHandler` to access HTTP and I also get `EIdIOHandlerPropInvalid ` exception. So I left `IdSSL` there.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried it on another computer, where no Delphi is installed, and I got exception `EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary`. So I have to include some SSL library to my app? Thanks for help.

Comment: @Legionar the **only** way `EIdIOHandlerPropInvalid` is raised is if an HTTPS url is requested without an `SSLIOHandler` assigned. Your HTTP url must have sent back a redirect to an HTTPS url. And yes, if you use `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, you have to deploy the [OpenSSL library](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) with your app.